# Splitting inversifyJS config file into multiple files

Tags: node.js, typescript, inversifyjs

I recently bumped into a backend project using Typescript and would like to implement IoC principle with the help of Inversify.js. Following the official documentation, I have one huge file named `inversify.config.ts` containing all my interfaces and classes that implement them:

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import { Container } from "inversify"
import TYPES from './types';

import { ModuleRepo } from '../repo/interfaces'
import { ModuleARepoImpl } from '../repo/moduleA'
import { ModuleBRepoImpl } from '../repo/moduleB'

import { ModuleService } from '../services/interfaces'
import { ModuleAServiceImpl } from '../services/moduleA'
import { ModuleBServiceImpl } from '../services/moduleB'

const container = Container();

container.bind<ModuleRepo>(TYPES.ModuleARepo).to(ModuleARepoImpl);
container.bind<ModuleRepo>(TYPES.ModuleBRepo).to(ModuleBRepoImpl);

container.bind<ModuleService>(TYPES.ModuleAService).to(ModuleAServiceImpl);
container.bind<ModuleService>(TYPES.ModuleBService).to(ModuleBServiceImpl);

export default container;
```

One big problem in the above setting is when the project gets complex, more modules are added resulting in a very long config file (imagine you have dozens of modules). My plan is to divide it into smaller config files, with `inversify.config.ts` remains the main file.

**consider the following settings:**

*./dependencies/interface/index.ts*

```
import { Container } from 'inversify';
export type InversifyContainer = Container

export interface BasicInterface {
        register(container: InversifyContainer): void
        readonly types: Object
    }
```

*./dependencies/moduleA/index.ts*

```
import {InversifyContainer, BasicDependencies} from '../interface';
import { ModuleRepo } from '../../repo/interfaces'
import { ModuleARepoImpl } from '../../repo/moduleA'
import { ModuleService } from '../../services/interfaces'
import { ModuleAServiceImpl } from '../../services/moduleA'

export class ModuleADependencies {
    register(container: InversifyContainer) {
           container.bind<ModuleRepo>(TYPES.ModuleARepo).to(ModuleARepoImpl);
           container.bind<ModuleService>(TYPES.ModuleAService).to(ModuleAServiceImpl);
    }

    readonly types = {
          ModuleARepo: Symbol('ModuleARepo'),
          ModuleAService: Symbol('ModuleAService'),
    }
}
```

*./dependencies/inversify.config.ts*

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import { Container } from "inversify"

import { ModuleADependencies } from './moduleA';
import { ModuleBDependencies } from './moduleB'; // consider moduleB also has the same file

const container = Container();
const registrationList = [ModuleADependencies, ModuleBDependencies];
for (const reg of registrationList) {
    new reg().register(container);
}

export default container;
```

*./dependencies/types.ts*

```
import { ModuleADependencies } from './moduleA';
import { ModuleBDependencies } from './moduleB';

const TYPES = {
    ...(new ModuleADependencies().types),
    ...(new ModuleBDependencies().types),
}

export default TYPES
```

However, this way I always have an error showing something like `Cannot read property of ModuleARepo of undefined` from the types. I browsed the internet however nobody seems to care about how lengthy and messy `inversify.config.ts` would be if it is in a complex project.

Hoping someone can help with this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your problem is described in the doc and [has a solution](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/container_modules.md).

Your solution is generally correct but there is a circular dependency

```
./dependencies/types.ts -> ./dependencies/moduleA/index.ts -> ./dependencies/types.ts
```

In `types` a new instance of class is created but the module that contain the class definition imports `types`. You don't list this import but use `TYPES.ModuleARepo` in `bind`.

To avoid it you can make `types` field static or move it out of the class into a separate exportable object. As a positive side effect of it, there will be no need to instantiate a class in `./dependencies/types.ts`.

Just in case please keep in mind that if you instantiate a class that has a Symbol as a field this symbol is unique for every instance since `Symbol('ModuleARepo') !== Symbol('ModuleARepo')`.

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ives-2x4u4?file=/src/dependencies/moduleA.ts)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and spotting out the problem. Since the beginning, I have suspected a circular dependency problem happening somewhere in my type import. However, I decided to just ask here and let it be a guideline for those facing a similar problem, especially to let somebody coin the term "ModuleContainer" as the solution which I also just knew it.